# Sorting contours and associated hierarchy

Tags: c++, sorting, opencv, stdvector

I am generating and sorting contours with OpenCV. I need to sort the contours by area and its associated hierarchy (CV_RETR_TREE). I have managed to sort the contours elegantly using a std::sort method, however, since the hierarchy and contours do not store record numbers (as far as I know), I cannot figure a way to relate the two databases together for the sort. So this means after sorting the contours my hierarchy becomes invalid. I can obviously populate additional databases with record numbers before sorting, but can anyone suggest a better solution?

Searching the web has been fruitless as practically every result for OpenCV contours also includes hierarchy.

```
void myContourFunction(Mat srcImage) {

    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

    findContours(srcImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv::Point(0,0));
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contoursPoly( contours.size() );

    for( int i = 0; i < numberContours; i++ ) {
            approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contoursPoly[i], 0.8, true );
    }

    std::sort(contoursPoly.begin(), contoursPoly.end(), compareContourAreas);
}

bool compareContourAreas ( std::vector<cv::Point> contour1, std::vector<cv::Point> contour2 ) {
    double i = fabs( contourArea(cv::Mat(contour1)) );
    double j = fabs( contourArea(cv::Mat(contour2)) );
    return ( i < j );
}
```

Comment: Is hierarchy[i] and contours[i] related? Then use a std::map to store the value as pairs (contours as key and hierarchy has value), sort the contours and then access it from map. Or you can use std::tuple. If the relation is not true then, this is invalid.

Comment: i don't think it's so bad to create those record numbers because they could be the indexes themselves. You only need to store the indexes (0, 1, ...n-1) into a vector and modify your comparison to work with that.